# Calculate difference beween two dates in hours and minutes

Tags: php, mysql, date, time

I use this code to calculate difference between two dates in hours and minutes :

```
$all = round(($date1timestamp - $date2timestamp) / 60);
$d = floor ($all / 1440);
$h = floor (($all - $d * 1440) / 60);
$m = $all - ($d * 1440) - ($h * 60);
```

Works perfectly but when I must multiple times to calculate difference between dates I must write code again and change values is there any simple way to calculate multiple times without rewrite code again ??

Comment: make it a function with parameters

Comment: Can you explain me how to do that ? I'm new with php function

Comment: For User-defined functions  See http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php

Comment: great question with excellent answers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

Function:

```
function date_difference ($date1timestamp, $date2timestamp) {
$all = round(($date1timestamp - $date2timestamp) / 60);
$d = floor ($all / 1440);
$h = floor (($all - $d * 1440) / 60);
$m = $all - ($d * 1440) - ($h * 60);
//Since you need just hours and mins
return array('hours'=>$h, 'mins'=>$m);
}
```

Calling the function:

```
$result = date_difference($date1timestamp, $date2timestamp);
```

Comment: yes but I have also $date3timestamp and $date4timestamp is that mean that I must write new function every time when I want to calculate dates ??

Comment: No, you just pass the pairs of timestamps, when you call the function eg. for 1352215735 (20121101) and 1352215759 (20121105), you call the function as `$result = date_difference(1352215759, 1352215735)`. The whole purpose of functions is to use it multiple times, without repetition of code.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you need to encapsulate this code in a function and then you can call the function whenever you need use it again rather than rewriting it.

```
function dateDiffHoursMins($date1timestamp, $date2timestamp)
{
   $all = round(($date1timestamp - $date2timestamp) / 60);
   $d = floor ($all / 1440);
   $h = floor (($all - $d * 1440) / 60);
   $m = $all - ($d * 1440) - ($h * 60);

   return array('d' => $d, 'h' => $h, 'm' => $m);
}
```

To use it, just call `dateDiffHoursMins()` and pass it the two timestamps. It will return an array so you can grab the values like this:

```
$diff = dateDiffHoursMins($time1, $time2);
$hours = $diff['h'];
echo("Hours: " . $hours);
```

This process of encapsulating code in a function is often referred to as keeping your code **DRY** which is an acronym that stands for **Dont Repeat Yourself**. This is a goal you should always strive for. It makes code faster to write and easier to debug. Imagine if you had copy/pasted that snippet 20 times throughout a file, and then found a bug in it. You would have to fix it in all 20 places, whereas with a function, you only have to fix it in one place.

Comment: +1. An example to call it `$difference = dateDiffHoursMins($date1timestamp , $date2timestamp)`. You can then access `$difference['d']`, `$difference['h']` and `$difference['m']`

Answer (score -1):

A good way to go about this is to think about it in terms of seconds.

The first step would be to pull the time stamp difference in seconds in SQL ($dbc is my database connection):

```
$timeQuery= mysqli_query($dbc,
                "SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(second,TIME1,TIME2) AS DIFF,
```

And then assign that to a variable

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($timeQuery)) {
    $totalTime = $row["DIFF"];
```

And then begin your conversions:

```
//Seconds in an hour
$unith =3600;       
//Seconds in a minute
$unitm =60;

//Number of hours and then the seconds remaining for minute calc
$hh = intval($totalTime / $unith);    
$ss_remaining = ($totalTime - ($hh * 3600));        
//Number of minutes and then the seconds remaing        
$mm = intval($ss_remaining / $unitm);    
$ss = ($ss_remaining - ($mm * 60));
```

And then you can print it like so:

```
$hh . ' : ' . $mm . ' : ' . $ss
```