# Time difference in minutes & seconds?

Tags: php, datetime, logic

Time difference in minutes & seconds

Problem : need convert difference is minutes & seconds only

```
    expected output : 130:04 (i:s)

    example : 

    $fromdate = "12/12/2013 21:00:02"

    $endData = "12/12/2013 23:10:06"

tried : date('i:s', strtotime( $endData) - strtotime( $fromdate));
```

Comment: and what have you tried so far please post your code so we can see where you've gone wrong.  if you were just expecting us to do the work for you then you've come to the wrong place

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer:

```
$to_time = strtotime("2008-12-13 10:42:00");
$from_time = strtotime("2008-12-13 10:21:00");
$totalMinutes = round(abs($to_time - $from_time) / 60,2);
$hours = intval($totalMinutes/60);
$minutes = $totalMinutes - ($hours * 60);
```

**EDITED.**

or as Teena Thmoas suggests in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13254037/calculate-difference-beween-two-dates-in-hours-and-minutes/13254140#13254140):

> Try:
>
> Function:
>
> ```
> function date_difference ($date1timestamp, $date2timestamp) {
> $all = round(($date1timestamp - $date2timestamp) / 60);
> $d = floor ($all / 1440);
> $h = floor (($all - $d * 1440) / 60);
> $m = $all - ($d * 1440) - ($h * 60);
> //Since you need just hours and mins
> return array('hours'=>$h, 'mins'=>$m);
> }
> ```
>
> Calling the function:
>
> ```
> $result = date_difference($date1timestamp, $date2timestamp);
> ```

Comment: thanks, but it show only minutes need minutes seconds also sergio

Comment: Now it you have minutes and hours as you asked.

Comment: no sergio ,130:04 (m:s)